# When strong naming an assembly: Which key to pick keypair or public key?

Tags: c#, .net, signing

When Strong typing an Assembly in .net, I can create the keypair (private) like this:

```
sn -k keypair.snk
```

And extracting the public key from it like that:

```
sn -p keypair.snk public.snk
```

But once I am in the property of a project, under Signing tab to select the Sign key,

which key do I choose? The keypair or public key?

In which circumstances within my organization would I need the public key?

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But once I am in the property of a project, under Signing tab to select the Sign key, which key do I choose?

You need the original file which contains both the public and private keys (the one generated with the `-k` option).

> In which circumstances within my organization would I need the public key?

Quote from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k5b5tt23.aspx):

> This public key can be used to delay sign an assembly using the
>   /delaysign+ and /keyfile options of the Assembly Linker (Al.exe). When
>   an assembly is delay signed, only the public key is set at compile
>   time and space is reserved in the file for the signature to be added
>   later when the private key is known.

Here's [another article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6f05ezxy.aspx) on MSDN explaining this process.

Answer (score 1):

The keypair is what you need because the keypair includes the private key.

The private key is used to generate a cryptographic hash of your assembly.  Then, when the Common Language Runtime loads your assembly, it uses the public key is used to validate contents of the assembly to make sure it hasn't been tampered with.